# Linking Image Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

I am trying to link my picture but it's not working
Any idea what I have forgotten?

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src="../img/img_avatar.png" alt="Card"></img>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Structure][1]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Images are self-closing tags, so you would use it like:

```html
<img src="../img/img_avatar.png" alt="Card" />
```

instead of what you're using.